# Using find from repository throwing a TransactionRequiredException

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

The next code is throwing a **TransactionRequiredException**:

```
$entity = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')
            ->find($id);
```

And the next one works just fine:

```
$entity = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->find('MyBundle:MyEntity', $id);
```

These are my composer dependencies:

```
"php"                                 : ">=5.5",
"symfony/symfony"                     : "~2.4",
"doctrine/orm"                        : "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle"            : "~1.2",
"doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle"   : "~2.2",
"twig/extensions"                     : "~1.0",
"symfony/assetic-bundle"              : "~2.3",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle"          : "~2.3",
"symfony/monolog-bundle"              : "~2.4",
"sensio/distribution-bundle"          : "~2.3",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle"       : "~2.3",
"sensio/generator-bundle"             : "~2.3",
"incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle"        : "~2.0@dev",
"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle"     : "~1.1",
"knplabs/knp-menu-bundle"             : "~2.0",
"knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle"           : "~1.2",
"white-october/pagerfanta-bundle"     : "~1.0",
"jms/di-extra-bundle"                 : "~1.4",
"lexik/form-filter-bundle"            : "~2.0"
```

The entity is extending an abstract one following the **MappedSuperclass** strategy and has some **OneToMany** and **ManyToMany** relations.

I really don't know why is this happening just trying to "read".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the problem just debugging a little bit...

`MyEntityRepository` is **overriding the find method** like:

```
public function find($id, $lockMode = LockMode::NONE, $lockVersion = null)
{
    return parent::find($id, $lockMode, $lockVersion);
}
```

But since [this revision](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/a6c8ab8a5f2e8217f2e3d015c27e8c9a1498b52f#diff-169f413cfbc3f35d72817e2b95ea3e00) we should set `$lockMode` to `null` *if no specific lock mode should be used during the search*.